# What does this divergence test tell us about these 2 series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I just had a Calculus test and one of the questions was something like this:

Consider the following series:
A = $\sum a_n$ and B = $\sum b_n$. If $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}a_n = 1$ and $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}b_n = 1$. What does the divergence test tell us about the series?

I thought they both diverge but there wasn't a choice to pick that. There was:

- Both converge.
- A converges, B diverges.
- A diverges and B may either converge or diverge.
- A may either converge/diverge and B converges.

What am I missing?

Comment: As you said, both diverges, so answer 3 is the correct one.

Comment: You are rigth! None of the options is correct.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: answer 3 is correct.

Comment: @joshua You are wrong. The third option  is also wrong since there is no chance for B to converge.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: I can mistaken, but if $B$ converges, then "$B$ converges or diverges" is true.

Comment: @joshua You cannot say that B may convege or diverge unless you have an example for each of the situations.

Comment: Looks to me like the question has been mis-quoted.  Should it be $\lim b_n= 0$.  I think that makes the proposed choices look more sensible. Or maybe $B=\prod b_n$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: Sorry to insist, but for me, if $P$ is a proposition, then $P\vee P^c$ is always true (which is $P$ is true or $P^c$ is true).

Comment: @joshua I'm really not sure who's right. But note the issue is not nuances of the word "or", rather the problem is exactly what "may" means...